# How do capacitors restore their charge?

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, capacitance

I understand the basics of how capacitors work, but I can’t seem to wrap my head around this.

If there is a non-conducting material in between the two plates, and you place a capacitor into a DC circuit:

1. How do electrons pass through?
2. How does a capacitor restore itself back to neutral?

Maybe I have a misunderstanding of how they work, but I would appreciate if someone can explain this to me!

Answer (score 5):

1. They don't, that's what makes it a capacitor.
2. When you remove the battery/voltage source, the capacitors will essentially run current in reverse to discharge.

Comment: Wow lol this has been driving me crazy all day, I couldn’t find anything online that simply answers my question without confusing me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a few key-concepts:

- electric fields attract and repell charges (depending on their poalrity)
- if charges can move freely, like in a metal, an el.filed will create a (temporary) current (*influence*), until there is a balance between sepating field and counter field by the separated charges
- if charges can't move, like in molecules, a neutrally charged object can still separate + and - charges; BECAUSE there is no conductivity, the molecule will be *polarized* by the field (+q to one end, -q to the other); as a result the molecular dipols will turn (macro-parameter: $\epsilon_r$)
- when influenced (=separated) charges can flow away (e.g. through an external electrical resistance), there is no way for the capacitor to recharge by its own (gone is gone)
- when they can't, applying a field will separate charges (the polarized plates will act as a dipol agaon), and when the field disappears, charges will recombine again
- isolate everything and the netto charge will not change (remaining zero if uncahrged in teh beginning, or pos or neg, if precharged beforehand)
- missing isolation means charges diappearing (try electrostatic experiements on a day with high humidity)